# How to get custom discord embeds for github.io website?

Tags: discord, embed

[image: This is what I mean]

[Source code](https://github.com/hypixelfarms/hypixelfarms.github.io)

[image: What my embed looks like.]

I just want to change some stuff like add a picture, change the colour of the blue strip, add some body text, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Use these meta tags inside your `index.html` file `<head>` tags.
 You have used the `og:title` tag, use the other two.

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="Write your desired title">
<meta property="og:description" content="Write the body text here">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://hypixelfarms.github.io/images/1.jpeg">
```

**These are for social sharing which use the `og` property, unlike Search Engines.**
For more information visit [this page of Css-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/essential-meta-tags-social-media/).

Comment: Glad, you used that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some Python code that will do what you're asking for. For `color`, set the variable to the hex code of any color you would like, and replace the `#` with `0x`. I have provided an example one that sets it to green. You can get the color code from [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=color+picker).

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Farms and More", 
        url="https://hypixelfarms.github.io/", 
        description="body text", 
        color=0x4ef207
    )
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="") # enter the URL location of the picture to use for the embed picture
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Go to this [website](https://medium.com/python-in-plain-english/send-an-embed-with-a-discord-bot-in-python-61d34c711046) for more detailed information on embed features.